# How to Create 2D list View

Tags: android

hi 
I am writing an Android App, in which  I need to display a List, Clicking on any list item should show another list besides that list item. Can anyone help me how can this be implemented in Android.

Thanks in Advancem

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

This one won't put a list view beside it but it'll drop down like the Froyo Call Log in the Contacts App.

Having 2 ListViews side by-side is very unusual from a design stand point and will probably confuse users.